# Halo effect sanding floors

Tags: floor, sanding, hardwood

I've used a drum sander and an edging sander to sand a floor. This has left the perimeter of the room a little different from the rest. 
What's the best way to blend both the regions ?
I used 36,60,80 and 120 grits with the drum and a 60 grit on the edger.

[image]

Comment: You MUST use the same grits with the edger as the drum sander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When re-finishing wood floors with drum and edge sanders one of the last steps is to blend the two areas with a floor machine sander. The floor machine is set-up for 100 and 120 grit sanding disks. Sanding this way between the two zones will even them out and blend in appearance.